# How can I get the list of available/supported keyboards' languages in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a WP7 app for which I created custom keyboards, now some of the keyboards are officially available in WP8.

I cannot publish the same app for both WP7 and WP8 separately, if I select to publish the app for the WP7, it is also available for WP8.

I want to implement a logic that if the OS of the phone is WP8 then it should not use the custom keyboard and vice versa.

It can be done in two ways:

1. I check for the available language, if the language (or the keyboard layout) is available on the phone, then it shouldn't use the custom keyboard.
2. I check for the OS, if it is 8 or later then it shouldn't use the custom keyboard.

**THE QUESTION**

How can I get the list of available/supported keyboards' languages? or How to get the WP OS version?

Comment: Even though the problem I had is solved, I am still looking for an answer to the question I asked. If someone could reply please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pubslih WP7.1 app to the WP Store, then you are right, both platforms would see that app.
But, if you publish seperately two XAPs to Store, one for WP 7.1 version and one for Windows Phone 8, then all WP 8 users would see only app that you make only for WP 8 platform.

Best regards

Comment: well, this is not exactly the answer to the question I asked. But it helped solving my problem. Thanks!